# How to inline declare a function inside a type?

Tags: typescript

I am fairly new to typescript and wanted to know how would I create a `type` that contains some properties and a function that works on the instance of the type similar to how a class does.

Something like:

```
export type Timer = {
  timerId: number;
  callback: () => void;
  clear() {
    if (timerId) {//}
    else{}
  }
}
```

Is this even a valid typescript way to declare types containing functions? Would appreciate some help in this. Thanks.

Comment: The type system is only a compiletime construct. It does not exist at runtime. What you ask for is impossible.

Comment: The type system _describes_ how something should _appear_ to the rest of the code, not how it actually _works_.

Comment: A type is just an alias of another type, not something you declare things on. You may want to use a class for this.

Comment: Feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What are you trying to accomplish and why wouldn't you want to use a `class` for this?

Comment: You've said that what you want is similar to a class, but you have not said why a class would not solve your problem.

Comment: I could use a class for this and that's what I ended up doing. I was trying to understand why this was not possible which some of the answers explain. Thanks.